# Git showing entire file is modified instead of showing modified small part of code

Tags: git

I searched for an answer to this in Google but came up with nothing.

In Windows, I configured git via eclipse. When I try to commit a modified file to my branch via Team --> commit, it shows only the modified lines as changed, but whenever my lead tries to merge the change to the branch it shows the whole file as changed

Can anyone suggest to me what is going to wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are on Windows or work with people on Windows, you have to be aware of the different line endings used on Windows and other platforms. You can [configure git to normalize these](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/) but you have to check with your team members what is appropriate here.

Comment: there might be multiple causes; are you using linux and windows (different OS), then you might have issues with the end-line character. Or Eclipse might be using tabs instead of spaces etc.

Comment: Check this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63062580/3361311

Answer (score 12):

This is most likely a line ending issue. Windows ends lines with `CRLF`, whereas other operating systems end them with `LF`. When files in a repository are changed by people using both types of operating systems, the fact that their respective editors change every line of a file to their particular flavor of line endings causes the behavior you are seeing.

Even if everyone on the team is using Windows, Git's attempts to "fix" this issue can *also* cause this issue to come up. This is because one way to tell Git to fix this issue is to set `core.autocrlf` to true. Doing this will cause Git to convert every `CRLF` to a `LF` on commit, and every `LF` to a `CRLF` on checkout. The problem is when different developers of the project have their `core.autocrlf` set to different values. So let's say you have `core.autocrlf` set to true, and another developer has it set to false. When you commit a file, Git will do the line ending conversion, and the repo will contain `LF` line endings. When the other developer checks out the file, no conversion will be done, and therefore every one of the lines in their local file (which have `CRLF`) will be different than in the repository.

The solution to this is to not rely on `core.autocrlf` to determine whether any of this normalization is done, since that can vary by machine. Instead, you want to have a `.gitattributes` file in your repo's root directory that determines whether normalization is done. What you want in there depends on if your whole team is using Windows or not.

**If your whole team uses Windows**: In this case, I would recommend disabling line ending normalization, as there is no need for it. To do this, put `* -text` in your `.gitattributes` file.

**If your team uses other OSs in addition to Windows**: In this case you do want line endings to be normalized. To make it consistent for everyone, put `* text=auto` in your `.gitattributes` file.

Comment: Had this same experience yesterday, can confirm this.

Answer (score 3):

Following has fixed the problem for me in Eclipse

1. Window -> Preferences -> Team -> Git -> Configuration
2. Click Add Entry button
3. Key = core.autocrlf, Value = false
4. Restart eclipse
5. Reset the problematic file to previous version
6. Merge the changes to file again
7. Commit.