# git diff is showing full file has changed for a single line change but only for few files in a directory

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I have come across a strange problem in **GIT**. Recently our codebase has moved to GIT from SVN. So, when I have cloned the repository on my local and I am doing single line change in a file, git diff is showing full file has changed (first all the content has deleted and then all the content added again). But strange thing is it's not happening for all the files.

e.g. I have changed (e.g. added a space after a line) my `app.js`, `index.html` and `gruntfile.js` where it's showing correct line diff for `app.js` and full file change for `index.html` and `gruntfile.js`

I have referred many stackoverflow articles and set `core.autocrlf` to `true` and `false` both but none of the setting worked.

Another strange thing is I am unable to reset that file also. Suppose in the above example if I do `git reset --hard`, it doesn't remove/revert the defected files from my local, here `app.js` has been reverted but other two did not revert. Finally I had to use `git checkout .` to revert all the files.

**Update:** This is my .gitattribute file content in the root directory.
`* text=auto`

And this is my .editorconfig file in the root directory.

```
root = true

[*]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 2
end_of_line = lf
charset = utf-8
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
insert_final_newline = true

[*.md]
trim_trailing_whitespace = false
```

Comment: How many commits have been made on the files which cannot be reverted?  By the way, `e.g.` is Latin for "for example," so you don't need to say `For e.g.`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen No local commits are there on any files. It's a fresh checkout.

Comment: How are you viewing the diff?  Locally, or from GitHub?

Comment: That sounds like unintentional EOL changes?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am viewing the diff locally using `git diff` command on git bash. I thought of pushing the changes to github and check the diff there but I can't push a file in this state where it's showing whole content has been deleted and added again. My reviewer/fellow team-mate will never understand what's the exact difference.

Comment: @wilx May be, but how to verify that changes? And I have tried changing core.autocrlf property also.

Comment: Changing core.autocrl won't change what's already in the repository.

Comment: @Gregg, I meant that first I have set `core.autocrlf` to `true` then checkout the code to my local repo and second time I have set `core.autocrlf` to `false` and then again I have checked out the code in different location.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This sounds like a problem with CRLF vs LF line endings to me.

I believe that SVN and GIT both store text files in their repositories with LF line endings, and that both convert between LF and CRLF line endings when checking files in and out of the repository from the working copy.

Unfortunately SVN and GIT have different ways of deciding which files are text files, so they don't always agree on whether line ending conversion is required.

GIT is pretty good at guessing but allows control using attributes - run "git help attributes" to get an explanation.

SVN uses svn properties on individual files, and these properties either have to be set manually or else via configured auto-props rules.

I'm guessing that the files were originally committed to SVN on Windows, that you're running GIT on Windows, and that you created the GIT repository using "git svn".

If so then my best guess is that your SVN repository didn't have svn properties set, so SVN stored files with CRLF line endings in the SVN repository without conversion.  If you then imported the SVN repository into a new GIT repository with "git svn" then the GIT repository will also contain CRLF line endings.  This is not the expected format for text files in the GIT repository, so it can cause problems.  In particular, I think "git diff" compares what is already in the repository (with CRLF line endings) with what would be committed to the repository (with LF line endings) and finds that every line is different.

One way to understand what's going on would be to clone the repository to a Linux machine with core.autocrlf = false (or not set).  In this case there wouldn't be any CRLF line ending conversion to confuse the matter, and you could see what the line endings in the checked out files are.  My guess is that they'll have CRLF line endings because of CRLF line endings stored in the GIT repository.

If my hypothesis is correct then I think you have 2 options:

(1) Fix the GIT repo to contain LF rather than CRLF line endings.
On Windows (with core.autocrlf=true) I think you could do this by touching every file (without making any changes), then commit all files that GIT reports as changed.
On Linux (with core.autocrlf=false) I think you could do it by running dos2unix on all of the text files and then committing them.

(2) Treat all files as binary rather than text so that GIT doesn't attempt line ending conversion at all.  I think you could do this by committing a .gitattributes file containing "* -text" (without the quotes).  The disadvantage of this is that you'll get CRLF line endings when checking out on Linux.

Comment: Great answer. Hope it will help me, I am little lost about how to proceed (as I can't play with the office repository, may be I will create a branch from master to test). I have added few more details in the main question. Can you conclude anything else from that!

Comment: I am yet to confirm how this repository has been migrated to GIT from SVN (I mean what were the settings at that time). Is there any way to check the line endings of any file on central (github) git repository?

Comment: Your local git repository should contain the same objects as the central git repository. You can show an object in your local git repository using "git show --raw".

For example
`git show --raw master:path/to/index.html >tmpfile`
then
`od -t x1 tmpfile`
(where od is a hex dump command available from the git bash shell)

Comment: I have tried it for single file. What I did is, I have added a space in `Gruntfile.js` (when it was showing full file has changed) and committed and pushed the same to central repo and now if I change anything in that file, it's showing correct diff. That means your hypothesis is correct. But can you tell me how can I do it for all the files in the repository(you said by touching every file, which I didn't understand) in a single commit on windows?

Comment: To be sure that my hypothesis is correct we would need to use "git show --raw" as described above to check the repository contents.

Comment: Also it seems that the git "text" attribute affects git behaviour in this case.  See "git help attributes" for a detailed explanation, and also "git help config" text about core.autocrlf.  In particular the behaviour I describe occurs when the text attribute is auto (.gitattributes '* text=auto') or set (e.g. .gitattributes '*.js text'), but not when the text attribute isn't set at all.  At least that's the case for git version 2.7.3.windows.1 - older versions might behave differently.  You can check the git attributes for a file using "git check-attr -a path/to/Gruntfile.js".

Comment: touch is a Linux command that updates the timestamp for a file.  touch is also available in the git bash shell on Windows.  I think touching a file is enough to make git check it more carefully, and depending on the git text attribute (see above) git might decide that the repository needs updating to fix line endings.

Comment: I think one way to update all the line endings in the git repository would be to create a .gitattributes file containing "* text-auto" (without quotes), then touch all files using a command such as "find * -type f | xargs touch" (again without quotes), then "git add ." / gitk (to check the results) / "git commit".  Beware that if you do this then lots of files are likely to be updated, and anybody else on your team is likely to have difficulties merging their commits on top of the fix commit.

Answer (score 6):

execute below command

```
cd repo<Project>
git config --global core.autocrlf true
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around it. Please edit your answer.

Comment: Just go to git repository and run the mentioned git command after doing this only difference will come.
This resolved my issue.

Answer (score 6):

This is expected behavior of GitLab and there is nothing wrong in this case. See the issue( https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/52936).
We may skip those white space changes from compression using GitLab UI.
Steps to hide/ignore white space changes.

1. Go to your merge request.
2. Navigate to change between section.
3. Click on the setting button, from right side of "change between section"
4. Unchecked the option "Show whitespace changes"

After doing this you the compare section will show only real changes. Below is the screenshot which you refer.

[image]